# Getting text in label that holds both text and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

My label text here

I used :

```
function Do(T){
var XcEP = $(T).parents().html().match(/^[-\s]*(.+?)[\s()\d]*$/,"i")[1]);
alert(XcEP);
}
```

The function above alerts:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Exep1" checked="checked" onclick="Do(this);"/> My label text here
```

But i want only "**My label text here**" to be in alert!

Any help is too much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(T).closest('label').text();
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately i got this:
$(T).closest is not a function

Comment: @unknown (yahoo), Upgrade to jQuery 1.3.

Comment: or just use `parents` instead of `closest`. But yeah, you don't want to be using older jQueries if you can help it.

Comment: Thank you bobince! 
This is good:
$(T).parents('LABEL').text().match(/^[-\s]*(.+?)[\s()\d]*$/,"i")[1];

About jquery version yes i'll update it!